# Meteor Multiple Find Multiple

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, multidimensional-array

Developing a new app in Meteor, which I have little experience in. Just got handlebars/blaze figured out I think, now Mongo..

I have a database filled with records like this (3000+ atm, production maybe larger):

```js
{
    name: "get happy wtf happy",
    manufacturer: "thingythreegrizzle",
    model: "much148",
    stock: 50,
    list_price: 868,
    price: 6380,
    rating: 1,
    info: "",
    tags: [
        {tag: "all"},
        {tag: "wow"},
        {tag: "fire"},
        {tag: "at"} 
    ],
    images: [
         {image: "http://www.a.com/2.jpg"},
         {image: "http://www.a.com/3.jpg"},
...}
```

All the records are using similar tag words 4 each currently (production will random).
I need my helper to return the best matches for the tag words.
So another record with 'all','wow','fire','woot' (not ordered) would be a likely desired return.
similar to

```
catalog.find({ 'tags.tag': {'$all': ['much','sad','prod','you']} })
```

but would return sorted by most matched **not all or nothing match**. Multiple cumbersome queries will work but I'm trying to do this in one shot if possible.

I'm totally up for reorganizing the DB but I don't know where to start.

Update: By 'best' I mean the record with the most matches. The closest to 100% match.

Comment: what do you mean by "best" matches?

Comment: By 'best' I mean the record with the most matches. The closest to 100% match.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do this without some coding. There is an algorithmic question here, too, which is how to do this fast and in particular without scanning the entire collection.

My suggestion would be to do the following:

1. turn the `tags` field into an array, so that mongodb can index over it;
2. add an index on tags, `catalog._ensureIndex('tags')`;
3. for each of your tags words perform a separate query on that tag alone, and store the resulting set;
4. use `_.reduce()`, or similar, to aggregate the sets of results you received into one set with counted repetitions;
5. sort by number of repetitions.